# How to create new react native Tag using button onpress

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am new in react native . In my project , I want to create new react native element (tag) after clicking on a button ( using onPress ) .
in web environment and using javascript , this is something like this :

```
document.createElement('tag_name');
```

is there a way to do something like this in react native ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a component that has the elements that you want it to have, and then with `useState` toggle that component to be shown when you press on a button.

Comment: Hello . thanks for your answer . but it is not what I need . In my case , I don't know how many element I need . I want to create some elements in a 'for' loop .  for example I want to create a 'view' for each item of the list I receive from server .